# Highstock with numbers instead of date in x-axis

Tags: highcharts

I need to output a plot on page, and I'm considering **Highstock** or Highcharts to implement this. Highstock interface is more preferable due to navigator pane showing the rest of plot after rezooming.

However my plot has numbers in x-asis, but not date/time. Is there any way to use Highstock with numerical x-scale? Or add similar navigator to Highcharts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Highstock's only type of xAxis is datetime, so using it with numbers is not an option. (Maybe if you make some tricky formatting actions and define a custom tooltip with the same formatting options it *might* be possible).

Leaves only Highcharts and there is an example called [master-detail chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail) that could meet your requirements.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 18):

Below `X Axis` formatter can be used with high Stock for displaying numbers in `X-Axis`:

```
xAxis: {labels: {   formatter: function () {return this.value;}} }
```

Comment: this is awesome. thanks. should do the same with navigator: { xAxis: {labels: {   formatter: function () {return this.value;}} } } that way also the navigator has the correct x-axis labels

Comment: And to display text, calibrate the dates to start at 0 and then use return myArray[this.value] in the function, where myArray is a variable that contains your text values.

Answer (score 1):

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'linear' // Other types are "logarithmic", "datetime" and "category"
},
```