# Highcharts scroll and zoom

Tags: highcharts

I am currently considering purchasing Highcharts or Highstock. I have looked through the example charts in both tools, and would appreciate it if someone can clarify this for me:

The data I need to plot is similar to time series financial data, but with numeric data (location in metres) on the x axis instead of dates. I am really impressed with the scroll and zoom function on the Highstocks chart. Is a similar feature available in the highcharts tool? If not, can the highstock charts be used with non-date data and labels on the x axis?

I looked at the other stack overflow questions related to Highcharts scroll and zoom, but what I specifically need to know is whether it has the same features as what I see in Highstock charts.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Since I posted this question, I found this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378693/highstock-with-numbers-instead-of-date-in-x-axis). It answers part of my question, but the alternative pointed to in HighCharts only seems to allow zoom, not the same zoom/scroll as I see in the HighStocks charts.

Comment: In general, navigator and scrollbar are parts of Highstock, and requires Highstock license. Similar attempt in Highcharts in this[Master-detail chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail) And there are not plans to add these features to the Highstock. Regarding your question with labels - it should be possible, but have never tested in that way (just change xAxis.type = 'linear' ).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Pawel. The link I posted above says however that Highstock chart x axis is only datetime. The master detail chart you linked to can zoom on an area, but as far as I can see you cannot drag the zoom area forward or back like in Highstock charts. Maybe I am missing something? So it seems I will have to look for another solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, just Highstock has more options to browse data. And here you have example of Highstock, with linear xAxis: http://jsfiddle.net/ykBKy/ (create chart using new Highcharts.Chart and use Highstock.js library)