# Highstock chart with data associated with time but not in x ais

Tags: highcharts

I want to add data to highstock where x axis is not time , How ever I want each of my data (x,y) to be associated with time as a third parameter and use that for scrolling or selecting range of data.Does anyone have any suggestion or illustation of doing this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378693/highstock-with-numbers-instead-of-date-in-x-axis

Answer (score 0):

The highstock requires x parameter as timestamp, to have a working scrollbar / rangeselector. If you need only scoller for highcharts you can do this in that way:

```
    xAxis:{
        min:0,
        max:5
    },
    scrollbar:{
        enabled:true
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5bh1s4kn/